# Why is `std::find_if` implemented by loop unrolling but `std::for_each` isn't?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, libstdc++

The `gcc` implementation of the standard library implements `find_if` using loop unrolling for RA iterators, and other search functions (`search`, `none_of`, `find`, etc) are implemented by calling `find_if` to reuse that optimization if it applies.

However, why is `find_if` the only function optimized that way, and not, for instance, `std::for_each`?

Comment: @uneven_mark The actual code.

Comment: [Reference](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L111) to the code you are talking about (for others).

Comment: Seems to have been written this way (and mostly unchanged) since 1998 when it was introduced, see [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/79f8bd54b87824aefef05ecc6431fb51215b1af7#diff-505e87197fdd5a41868acfc86a9abb27R149).

Comment: There is an [open bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87264) relating to this and a [closed one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84170) in which the argument is made that this made sense as an optimization when it was written but would need to be benchmarked before any changes are made today. I don't know why it was applied only to `find_if` and not other algorithms.

Comment: I think the only people who could answer this are people who created or managed gcc.